# Can't do INSERT INTO...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in vb Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to make a request which will insert data or update if the entry exists.

I tried:

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM dbo_VUE_GATE_ELEVES WHERE Annee = " & intAnneeScolaire)

While Not rs.EOF
    DoCmd.RunSQL ("INSERT INTO Eleve(Fiche, Nom, Prenom, Courriel) VALUES (rs!Fiche, '" & rs!Nom & "', '" & rs!Prenom & "', '" & rs!Courriel & "') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Nom = '" & rs!Nom & "', Prenom = '" & rs!Prenom & "', Courriel = '" & rs!Courriel & "'")
    rs.MoveNext
Wend
```

I always get the following error:

> "Error 3137 - Missing semicolon(;) at end of SQL statement."

And yes I tried adding a semicolon.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: ` VALUES (rs!Fiche, '"` - you are attempting to insert the literal string "rs!fiche" not the value of that field.  Compare that with the other fields.

Comment: Possibly also relevant - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28744411/is-there-an-equivalent-to-on-duplicate-key-update-in-access  or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199417/upserting-in-ms-access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Access does support a single statement to handle upsert needs like `ON DUPLICATE KEY` or `MERGE`, consider two action queries without any quotation or concatenation or recordset looping. Below separates SQL from VBA and uses parameterization for the insert-select query.

**SQL** *(save both as saved queries in Access .accdb file)*

```sql
PARAMETERS prmintAnneeScolaire INTEGER;
INSERT INTO Eleve (Fiche, Nom, Prenom, Courriel)
SELECT d.Fiche, d.Nom, d.Prenom, d.Courriel
FROM dbo_VUE_GATE_ELEVES d
WHERE d.Fiche NOT IN (SELECT Fiche FROM Eleve)
  AND d.Annee = [prmintAnneeScolaire]
```

```
UPDATE Eleve e INNER JOIN dbo_VUE_GATE_ELEVES d ON e.Fiche = d.Fiche
SET e.Nom = d.Nom,
    e.Prenom = d.Prenom,
    e.Courriel = d.Courriel
```

**VBA**

```vb
' APPEND NEW DATA
With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("mySavedAppendQuery")
    .Parameters("prmintAnneeScolaire") = intAnneeScolaire
    .Execute dbFailOnError
End With

' UPDATE EXISTING DATA
CurrentDb.Execute "mySavedUpdateQuery"
```